# Rank of $GL_n(R)$ and rank of the space of all singular matrices

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry

Let $M_n(R)$ be the space of all n × n matrices. What I have learned from the class is that
$SL_n(R)$ is a submanifold of $GL_n(R)$ with rank $n^2-1$.

Then is $GL_n(R)$ a submanifold of $M_n(R)$ with rank $n^2$? (Of course, $GL_n(R)$ would have the same rank as $M_n(R)$ then.)

Also, let $Zero_n(R)$ be the space of all singular matrices. Then, is $Zero_n(R)$ even a submanifold of $M_n(R)$? Then what is the rank of $Zero_n(R)$?

Comment: $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ so it is a submanifold of dimension $n^2$. The set of singular matrices is the zero level set of the determinant function and is not an embedded submanifold when $n > 1$. You can analyze the case $n = 2$ where the determinant is just a quadratic form quite explicitly. BTW, the terminology "rank of a manifold" instead of "dimension of a manifold" is not standard and can be confusing, especially considering the matrices themselves have a rank.